# Golang how do I simulate users idling on a webpage?

Tags: go

Hi guys I was wondering how I might simulate users idling a webpage

I'm currently making a part of my website that will show how many concurrent connections there are to the server right now I don't really have access to more than 1 computer.

It works and shows 1 person online, but I want to write a small little go program that I can set a variable to say, 100 people, and launch it, it will stay running and then see if my site correctly shows 100 people connected to it.

I had something like

package main

import (
    "net"
)

```
func main() {
    go connectToServer()
    go connectToServer()
    go connectToServer()
}

func connectToServer() {
    servAddr := "http://localhost:1337"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", servAddr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

It runs but I don't know if this is the right way to do it, also since they're go routines and are ending almost instantly my program starts then stops right away so I need a way to keep the connections alive without the program stopping right away, any information would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How will your users be "connected"? Is there a persistent connection to the server, i.e with websocket?

Comment: Yes sorry they will be connected through websockets or a fallback to a ping from ajax if websockets isn't supported